# How to resize all HTML headings by a fixed proportion?

Tags: html, css, font-size

[Dancing Script](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dancing+Script?query=dancing#pairings) is a font that looks (at least for me) intrinsically smaller than, say, *Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif*:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: horizontal;
  align-items: flex-end;

}
body {
  --main-font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  --handwritten-font: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.handwritten {
  font-family: var(--handwritten-font);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://www.webmasterpoint.org/programmazione/html5/guida-html5/struttura-sito-header-nav-section-article-aside-footer-nuovo-doctype.html -->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap');
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div>
          <h1>Ciao</h1>
          <h1 class="handwritten">Ciao</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Ciao</h2>
          <h2 class="handwritten">Ciao</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Ciao</h3>
          <h3 class="handwritten">Ciao</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Ciao</h4>
          <h4 class="handwritten">Ciao</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5>Ciao</h5>
          <h5 class="handwritten">Ciao</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h6>Ciao</h6>
          <h6 class="handwritten">Ciao</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Therefore, to give an example, where I use `h2` tag with the font `Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`, I would like to use `h1`-sized font `Dancing Script, cursive`, so I'd go for a rule like this:

```css
/* browser's defaults */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em
}
/* ... and so on */

/* my styles */
h1.handwritten-font {
  /* increas font-size by the 2em/1.5em ratio */;
}

h2.handwritten-font {
  /* increas font-size by the 2em/1.5em ratio */;
}
/* ... and so on */
```

but obviously the rule `font-size: calc(2em/1.5em);` is not what is needed:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --main-font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  --handwritten-font: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

.handwritten {
  font-family: var(--handwritten-font);
}

div > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em
}

/* these have no effect */
h1.handwritten {
  font-size: calc(2em/1.5em);
}

h2.handwritten {
  font-size: calc(2em/1.5em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://www.webmasterpoint.org/programmazione/html5/guida-html5/struttura-sito-header-nav-section-article-aside-footer-nuovo-doctype.html -->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap');
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div>
          <h1>Ciao</h1>
          <h1 class="handwritten">Ciao</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Ciao</h2>
          <h2 class="handwritten">Ciao</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Ciao</h3>
          <h3 class="handwritten">Ciao</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Ciao</h4>
          <h4 class="handwritten">Ciao</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5>Ciao</h5>
          <h5 class="handwritten">Ciao</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h6>Ciao</h6>
          <h6 class="handwritten">Ciao</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect I may not have fully understood because I can't see why the answer isn't to set font-size: calc(2em* 2 / 1.5) [just to spell it out - there is of course no need to get CSS to do the arithmetic if variables aren't involved].

Comment: Maybe the [`font-size-adjust`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_font-size-adjust.asp) property might be helpful.

Comment: I don't think font-size-adjust is relevant here (though I could be wrong). Could you say why font-size: calc(2em * 2 / 1.5) isn't suitable?

Comment: @AHaworth, if I do `h1.handwritten { font-size: calc(2em * 2/1.5); }`, `h2.handwritten { font-size: calc(2em * 2/1.5); }`, and so on, I'll end up with all headings of the same `font-size`, whereas I want each `hN.handwritten` to have a `font-size` which is `calc(2/1.5)` times the `font-size` of the corresponding `hN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the 'plain' header font-sizes as CSS variables, then use those to calculate the 2/1.5 size for the handwritten version (though possibly you might want finer control with each hn having its own resizing, but this snippet uses the same factor for all).

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      --main-font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      --handwritten-font: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
      font-family: var(--main-font);
    }
    
    .handwritten {
      font-family: var(--handwritten-font);
    }
    
    div > div {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    h1 {
      --hem: 2em;
      font-size: var(--hem);
    }
    
    h2 {
      --hem: 1.5em;
      font-size: var(--hem);
    }
    
    .handwritten {
      font-size: calc(var(--hem) * 2 / 1.5);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://www.webmasterpoint.org/programmazione/html5/guida-html5/struttura-sito-header-nav-section-article-aside-footer-nuovo-doctype.html -->
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>Ciao</h1>
      <h1 class="handwritten">Ciao</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Ciao</h2>
      <h2 class="handwritten">Ciao</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```